# Convert a hashtable to a sorted Array in O(log(k)*k + n)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, sorting, time

So in my data structures lecture I was told that it's possible to convert a hashtable with k keys and n elements to a sorted array in amortized O(log(k)*k + n). However, there was no reasoning behind it. I found it kind of confusing why I tried to find an algorithm which does that.

I can't come up with one. I guess it has to be a commonly known one since we just noted it without proof but I can't find it. Do you know a solution for this problem?

Comment: Are the items which share the same key *sorted* within the hash table?

Comment: Sorted based on the value of their key in the hash table, or based on some other criterion?

Comment: You must describe precisely the input data and the output data if you want an algorithm, so what is exactly a hashtable with k keys and n elements and what is exactly this sorted array. Also are k and n allowed to vary independantly ?

Comment: What's the difference between a key and an element in a hashtable? Do you mean the size of the table is n, and there are currently k keys in it?

Comment: @G.Bach: Or the values are lists of some sort. So there are k keys with k values (lists), but a total of n elements in all of the lists combined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean sorted by keys, it's k*log(k) to sort the keys and n to insert the elements based on the sorted keys. Hence O(klog(k) + n). The algorithm is:

1. Sort the keys (probably in a new array)
2. Create an empty array with room for n elements
3. Iterate over the sorted key array and insert all of the elements for each key in the new array

Step 1 takes O(klog(k)) operations and step 3 takes O(n).